# jooq - execute string as subquery

Tags: java, sql, subquery, jooq

I have a query, represented by a string:

```
final String q = "select 1 union select 2 union select 3";
```

This string comes from an external source (configuration), hence it is a string. In the real scenario, the query is ofcourse more meaningful.

I would like to execute this query as a subquery within a jOOQ type-safe query. The following works, but it is not really what I want:

```
    System.out.println(<context>.select().from(DSL.table("person")).where(DSL.field("identifier").in(
            <context>.fetch(q).intoArray(0)
    )).fetch());
```

The problem here is that I am essentially executing two queries. This introduces overhead.

Is it possible to execute the string-query as a real subquery? I somehow have to convert the string-query to a `Select<Record1>` instance (I guess), but I cannot find how to do that.

Comment: That won't make a difference; even if this were pure jooq, a subquery would be executed.

Comment: True, but the intermediate results from the subquery will not be sent to the  client and back to the server (for the execution of the outer query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of places where you can inject a `Select` type as [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). For instance:

#### As a plain SQL WHERE clause:

```
<context>.select()
         .from(DSL.table("person"))
         .where(
             "identifier in ({0})", DSL.resultQuery(q)
         )
         .fetch();
```

#### As a plain SQL Table:

```
<context>.select()
         .from(DSL.table("person"))
         .where(DSL.field("identifier").in(
             DSL.select().from("(" + q + ")")
         ))
         .fetch();
```

There are others. The important thing to notice is that by using plain SQL, you have the possibility to embed your own SQL strings in templates that have enumerated placeholders

```
... {0} ... {1} ...
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Isn't there a case for adding the `in(String, QueryPart...)` function? I am not found of the first solution, since we are not using the `in()` function. I am also not found of the second solution, since we are `selecting from a select statement`. This is being pedantic though.

Comment: Or even better, something like this: `.in(DSL.query("..."))`

Comment: @JefJedrison: `in(String, QueryPart...)` is not possible, because it would conflict with `in(T...)`, especially in your case where you bind `<T>` to `Object`. *"I am not found of the first solution, since we are not using the in() function"* - Well, I can only answer the question that you asked, not the one you had in mind :). *"I am also not found of the second solution, since we are selecting from a select statement"* - I agree that's not optimal. *"Or even better, something like this: .in(DSL.query("..."))"* There is no lean way to create a `Select<Record1<T>>` this way

Comment: @JefJedrison: You're welcome. I agree that there is room for improvement for your use-case, but Stack Overflow comments are a bit tricky to discuss these things. Maybe, we continue discussing this on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user)?

Comment: I agree we should'nt discuss on SO. I will register myself to the mailing list later this week. Thank you for your endless support!